# Element drag working only once on webview

Tags: android, webview, draggable, gsap, long-click

I have a page that got elements that when long clicked makes it draggable. It works on the `Chrome` app but not on my `WebView`.

This is my `WebSettings`.

```
String UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19" +
                    " (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19";

WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

settings.setUserAgentString(UA);
```

I also already enabled long click on the webview by doing `webView.setLongClickable(true);`

I can now drag the elements after long clicking. But I can only drag 1. After dragging 1 element, I can't drag anything anymore.

The page the webview loads GSAP TweenMax, Draggable, CSSPlugin if that infos will help.

Comment: this is happening to me too, did you solve it?

Comment: The only thing that solved that for me is use a Lollipop device. I haven't done more research or testing about it but that's the only thing that made it work for me.

Comment: I opened a issue on gsap repo, just in case if you wanna keep an eye to the issue https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/issues/296

Comment: Lol. I already did that.